# Laser diffraction by synthetic Opal: how to determine "$d$"?

Tags: diffraction, braggs-law

I'm doing some measurements with laser diffraction on a cut cube of synthetic opal. Here's a stock photo of it:

[image: Opal]

The shimmering colours are due to diffraction of visible light on intermolecular planes (believed about $100\,\mathrm{nm}$ apart).

I want to determine the value(s?) of the distance "$d$" between these intermolecular planes using three lasers (red, green and purple) of known wavelength. I'm getting very clear diffraction with all three but I'm mystified how to calculate $d$ from my results.

For diffraction I would use:

[image: Bragg diffraction]

with the formula:

$$n\lambda = d(\sin\alpha+\sin\beta)\tag{1}$$

The problem is that I don't really  know the orientation of the planes with respect to the sides of the cube.

This diagram may shed some light on my problem:

[image: Opal 2]

The black edged square is the Opal cube.

The thick purple line represents some intermolecular planes and $\alpha'$ the planes' orientation vis-avis the cube.

$\theta$ is the angle of incidence of some laser rays vis-a-vis the cube.

We then have the angular relationships:

$$\alpha=\theta + \alpha'$$
and:
$$\beta=\theta'-(\theta+\alpha')$$

So that:

$$n\lambda = d\left[\sin(\theta + \alpha') +\sin(\theta'-(\theta+\alpha'))\right]\tag{2}$$

The problem is that $\alpha'$ is unknown and that only $\theta$ and $\theta'$ are directly measurable.

I've tried expanding $(2)$ using addition/subtraction trigonometric identities but that only lead to an intractable mess.

One idea would be to rotate the cube in such a way that the incident rays and diffracted rays coincide.

**Does anyone know a way forward?**

---

I think I've found one. [You can find my efforts here (Part I)](https://dispatches-from-the-us-of-mordor.blogspot.com/2021/12/bragg-diffraction-by-synthetic-opal-of.html).

And [the concluding Part II, here](https://dispatches-from-the-us-of-mordor.blogspot.com/2021/12/bragg-diffraction-by-synthetic-opal-of_17.html).

Comment: So you know all the parameters except $d$ and $\alpha'$. You also have several lasers. Why not do two measurements with two $\lambda$s and solve two simultaneous equations (possibly numerically)?

Comment: @Ruslan I've found the solution with just one laser. It's in Part II of my experiment, to be published later. Thank you.

Comment: @Ruslan Do you know why most sources still cite $n\lambda=2d\sin\alpha$ when really it should be $n\lambda=2d(\sin\alpha+\sin\beta)$ ?

Comment: I think in most cases the surface is assumed to be parallel to a molecular plane. In this case $\alpha=\beta$.

Comment: In fact, even if it's not parallel, the peaks should still be described by the usual formula with $\alpha=\beta$. Only relative brightness should change, cf. blazed diffraction grating.

Comment: @Ruslan Yes, in the case of a blazed diffraction grating. But in the case of an actual crystal (or 'pseudo-crystal' - my case) then not.  $n\lambda=2d\sin\alpha$ seems like a simplification in textbooks, due to the usual *inertia*. Certainly my work shows very clearly $\alpha \neq \beta$...

Comment: Well, looking forward to reading your work...

Comment: @RuslanThese are the results of the $d$ determination: https://dispatches-from-the-us-of-mordor.blogspot.com/2021/12/bragg-diffraction-by-synthetic-opal-of_17.html I'll be testing the model later on this week.

Comment: I wonder why the output diffracted beam in your photo in Part I has roughly the same thickness as the input one. It must have travelled through the whole cube and scattered all around, with only some directions (but not points along the beam!) being enhanced by constructive interference. For this reason I'd expect the diffracted beam to be as wide as the output surface.

Comment: @Ruslan That's an interesting observation but as a direct observer I can't confirm or infirm the thicknesses of the beams are the same. I have also wondered about other diffracting planes. More research into that is really needed.